# Graph squashed when opening excel on certain computers

Tags: excel, graph, windows-xp, squash

I'm having some trouble with excel's charts - at my office, certain people opening a particular spreadsheet end up with graphs that look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpwoE.jpg

Everyone is on Windows XP, using a mixture of Excel 2003 and 2007. Only some people get this bug, and IT can't work out why. I can't really post anything more specific or any logs as the data is commercially sensitive, but I was hoping this might be a common fault with an easy fix.

Thanks for your help,